# How to use group_by variable as an exclusion value with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
(dat  = data_frame(v1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 4)), v2 = 1:10))
# A tibble: 10 × 2
#       v1    v2
#    <chr> <int>
# 1      a     1
# 2      a     2
# 3      a     3
# 4      b     4
# 5      b     5
# 6      b     6
# 7      c     7
# 8      c     8
# 9      c     9
# 10     c    10
```

What I want to be able to do is compute a sum for each group (i.e. "a", "b", and "c") that is equal to the sum of `v2` where `v1` is **not equal** to the grouping value. So it should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#      v1   sum
#   <chr> <int>
# 1     a    49
# 2     b    40
# 3     c    21
```

Based on what I've been seeing online, this looks like a job for `do`, but I can't wrap my head around how to achieve this. I thought it would look something like this:

```
x %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  do(data.frame(sum=sum(.$v2[x$v1 != unique(.$v1)])))
```

But this just gives me a dataframe with `sum` equal to `NA` for all three groups. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe using an intermediate column it is easier:

```
dat %>% mutate(total = sum(v2)) %>% group_by(v1) %>% summarize(sum = max(total) - sum(v2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `nest` and then index the list column negatively:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% nest(v2) %>% mutate(sum = map_int(seq(n()), ~sum(unlist(data[-.x]))))

## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##      v1             data   sum
##   <chr>           <list> <int>
## 1     a <tibble [3 × 1]>    49
## 2     b <tibble [3 × 1]>    40
## 3     c <tibble [4 × 1]>    21
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's really easy to save the original data and align the computed values with them.

Comment: This gives me an error, saying that object of type closure is not subsettable. Is this stemming from `-.x`? If not, where is the `-.x` coming from?

Comment: `.x` is the variable in `purrr::map_int`'s anonymous function syntax. The error comes from trying to subset a function. In this case, `data` is the default name of the list column that `tidy::nest` creates, but is also the name of a base R function, so either `v2` is not getting nested properly (try without the `mutate` and check) or `mutate` is getting confused about names (so rename the column in `nest` or prefix it with `.$` to specify).

Answer (score 0):

@67342343's solution seems like the way to go here. If you have more complex overlapping/excluded groups, then maybe something like the following would be helpful:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat = data_frame(v1 = rep(letters[1:5], 3), v2 = 1:(5*3))

c(combn(unique(dat$v1),2, simplify=FALSE),
  combn(unique(dat$v1),3, simplify=FALSE)) %>%
  map_df(~ dat %>% 
           group_by(v1) %>% 
           summarise(v2 = sum(v2)) %>%
           filter(v1 %in% .x) %>%
           ungroup %>%
           summarise(groups = paste(.x,collapse=","),
                     sum = sum(v2)))
```

> ```
>    groups   sum
> 1     a,b    39
> 2     a,c    42
> 3     a,d    45
> 4     a,e    48
> 5     b,c    45
> ...
> 18  b,c,e    75
> 19  b,d,e    78
> 20  c,d,e    81
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A small function without using dplyr:

```
dat  <- data_frame(v1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 4)), v2 = 1:10)

test_func<-function(df){
      a<-sum(df[df$v1 != "a",][,2])
      b<-sum(df[df$v1 != "b",][,2])
      c<-sum(df[df$v1 != "c",][,2])
      out<-rbind(a,b,c)
      return(out)
}

test_func(dat)

  [,1]
a   49
b   40
c   21
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple:

```
dat %>% group_by(v1) %>% summarize(foo = sum(dat$v2) - sum(v2))
```

This is crass if you are in the middle of a long dplyr chain and have modified `dat`. (But then, why not relax and just store your data?)